Inclusions of product of groups
I have the following group-theoretic question, where I don't know what really could/should happen:
I have three groups, $G_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, $G_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and $H \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.
Furthermore, I know that $G_1 \subseteq G_2$ and $H \subseteq G_2$.
Does this already imply that $G_1 \subseteq H$?

Let me denote the cyclic group of order $k$ by $C_k$, written multiplicatively.
Claim. Let $G_2=C_n\times C_n$, with the factors generated by $x$ and $y$, and let $m$ be a positive divisor of $n$. The only subgroup of $G_2$ isomorphic to $C_m\times C_m$ is $\langle x^{n/m}\rangle\times\langle y^{n/m}\rangle$.
(Note that $C_n=\langle x\rangle$ has a unique subgroup of order $m$; this is the subgroup generated by $x^{n/m}$.)
Let $K$ be a subgroup of $G_2$ isomorphic to $C_m\times C_m$. Let $\pi_i\colon G_2\to C_n$ be the projection onto the $i$th coordinate. Then $K\subseteq \pi_1(K)\times\pi_2(K)$. Since $\pi_i(K)$ has exponent $m$ and is a subgroup of $C_n$, it is cyclic of order $k_i$ with $k_i\mid m$. The order of $\pi_1(K)\times\pi_2(K)$ is $k_1k_2$. Since it must be at least $m^2$, and each $k_i$ is a divisor of $m$, we must have $k_1=k_2=m$. Thus, $K$ is contained in the subgroup $\langle x^{n/m}\rangle \times \langle y^{n/m}\rangle$, and by order considerations it must be equal to it.
So $G_1$ is exactly what you expect it to be.
Now look at $H$. This subgroup of $G_2$ contains at least one  subgroup isomorphic to $C_m\times C_m$, which is itself a subgroup of $G_2$. But we just said that the only subgroup of $G_2$ that is isomorphic to $C_m\times C_m$ is $G_1$, and hence the only subgroup of $H$ that is isomorphic to $C_m\times C_m$ is $G_1$. Thus, we must have $G_1\subseteq H$, as desired.
